VS 2022 pair to mac - error starting broker
I succesfully connected my PC to my Macbook the first time trying using pair to mac in VS 2022 to simulate my work in IOS, then trying a couple of days later I can no longer get it to work. I've tried all the solutions I can find and nothing has worked.
I always get this error:
An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
An error occurred while trying to start Broker 17.12.0.153
I looked in the logs and this is all I found:
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext Error: 0 : An error occurred while trying to start the Broker...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.Exceptions.AgentInitializationException: An error occurred while trying to start Broker 17.12.0.153 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Reactive.Subjects.AsyncSubject`1.GetResult()
at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingRemoteCommands.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingRemoteCommands.cs:line 52
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingRemoteCommands.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingRemoteCommands.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.d__121.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingService.cs:line 1021
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService.d__111.MoveNext() in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\MessagingService.cs:line 813: 12/10/2024 09:06:14Z
DateTime=2024-12-10T09:06:14.9635556Z: 12/10/2024 09:06:14Z
Can add the full log if needed but couldn't see anything useful
I'm new to working with Macos so there's a chance I'm missing something obvious, any help is appreciated

Have a look at this report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-trying-to-pair-Visual-Studio-1712/10806194?space=62&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=fma

I would encourage you to try a couple of things in order to see if there’s any progress. First, install the latest VS stable version, then do the steps below:
1 - Look for other zombie Broker processes running on your Mac. To do so, run the follwing on a terminal in your Mac (ensure to not have any active connection in VS already): ps -A | grep XMA. If you see any result, kill the processes by running kill -9 , where  is the process id that the first command shown
2 - Restart your Mac (just in case your current session is in a weird state)
3 - Try to start the broker manually. This is just a test in your Mac that doens’t affect VS. Go to /Users//Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Agents/Broker/, where  is your Mac user (the same you use in Pair To Mac) and  is the version of the Broker. In case you have more than one version folder, use the latest by “Date Modified”. Then open a terminal in the Mac pointing to that folder and run: dotnet Broker.dll -port=45555

This led me to find that the broker service needed .NET 8.0 which was not installed.

Thank you - after hours of trial and error, I finally stumbled upon this. And following step 3, I came to the same conclusion - .NET 8 was not installed (I had .NET 9)

I posted a solution that works in my environment at the Developer Community link already mentioned above but also add the details here per recommendation, see beloe https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-trying-to-pair-Visual-Studio-1712/10806194?space=62&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=fma
I have spent considerable hours on this topic and arrived at a stable setup, at least in my environment. Unfortunately, there are too many variables involved to pinpoint the exact root cause of the Windows/Mac communication failures. But I was able to verify a specific configuration that works on 3 Windows machines and my Mac. I tested this with several MAUI projects, iOS-Emulators and an iPhone connected to the Mac wired as well as via WiFi. One time I had to kill a lingering XMA process on the Mac (ps -A | grep XMA -> then kill {process-id}) but that was only one time out of 30 or so tests.
What appears to be important, especially with XCode 16.2 is to ensure you use .NET SDK 9.0.101. Also note the exact version numbers of the MAUI workloads (maui-windows, ios, maccatalyst, android). Somehow a different (newer) version slipped in during one installation and it did NOT work. I had to remove and either try with dotnet workload install or the Visual Studio Installer. On one Windows machine I had very old .NET SDKs and Runtimes that the uninstaller could not remove (and locating all the MSIs was too time consuming), so I wiped everything and reinstalled Visual Studio from scratch.
Long story short, with the exact below versions, it works robustly now. Note also the 3 runtimes on the Windows machine (.NET 6, 8 and 9) but only the 9.0.101 SDK.
I hope this helps.
Windows 11 Pro
OS Version: 24H2 (OS Build 26100.2605)
Visual Studio Version 17.12.3
dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
Version: 9.0.101
Commit: eedb237549
Workload version: 9.0.100-manifests.4a280210
MSBuild version: 17.12.12+1cce77968
Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Windows
OS Version: 10.0.26100
OS Platform: Windows
RID: win-x64
Base Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.101\
.NET workloads installed:
[maui-windows]
Installation Source: VS 17.12.35527.113
Manifest Version: 9.0.0/9.0.100
Manifest Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\9.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maui\9.0.0\WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: Msi
[maccatalyst]
Installation Source: VS 17.12.35527.113
Manifest Version: 18.1.9163/9.0.100
Manifest Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\9.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst\18.1.9163\WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: Msi
[ios]
Installation Source: VS 17.12.35527.113
Manifest Version: 18.1.9163/9.0.100
Manifest Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\9.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\18.1.9163\WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: Msi
[android]
Installation Source: VS 17.12.35527.113
Manifest Version: 35.0.7/9.0.100
Manifest Path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\9.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.android\35.0.7\WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: Msi
Configured to use workload sets when installing new manifests.
Workloads are configured to install and update using workload versions, but none were found. Run “dotnet workload restore” to install a workload version.
Host:
Version: 9.0.0
Architecture: x64
Commit: 9d5a6a9aa4
.NET SDKs installed:
9.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.36 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.36 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.36 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 9.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Other architectures found:
x86 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]
Environment variables:
Not set
global.json file:
Not found
Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
dotnet workload list
Workload version: 9.0.100-manifests.4a280210
Installed Workload Id Installation Source
android VS 17.12.35527.113
ios VS 17.12.35527.113
maccatalyst VS 17.12.35527.113
maui-windows VS 17.12.35527.113
Use dotnet workload search to find additional workloads to install.
Strangely, the workload list does not include version numbers. In older versions of the tool and on MacOS it does so as well.
Mac
Operating System is 15.2 (24C101)
Xcode Version 16.2 (16C5032a)
dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
Version: 9.0.101
Commit: eedb237549
Workload version: 9.0.100-manifests.1e472b70
MSBuild version: 17.12.12+1cce77968
Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Mac OS X
OS Version: 15.2
OS Platform: Darwin
RID: osx-arm64
Base Path: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/9.0.101/
.NET workloads installed:
[maui-ios]
Installation Source: SDK 9.0.100
Manifest Version: 9.0.0/9.0.100
Manifest Path: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/9.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/9.0.0/WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: FileBased
[maui]
Installation Source: SDK 9.0.100
Manifest Version: 9.0.0/9.0.100
Manifest Path: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/9.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/9.0.0/WorkloadManifest.json
Install Type: FileBased
Configured to use loose manifests when installing new manifests.
Host:
Version: 9.0.0
Architecture: arm64
Commit: 9d5a6a9aa4
.NET SDKs installed:
8.0.404 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
9.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 9.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 9.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Other architectures found:
None
Environment variables:
Not set
global.json file:
Not found
Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/info
Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
dotnet workload list
Installed Workload Id Manifest Version Installation Source
maui 9.0.0/9.0.100 SDK 9.0.100
maui-ios 9.0.0/9.0.100 SDK 9.0.100
Hope this helps someone. It can be a very time-consuming troubleshooting journey.

I would be better to post the solution here, as the posted link could change/disappear in the future (rendering this answer meaningless).
